# How can I convert multiple variables to Date with different date formats?

Tags: r, date

My data looks like this,

```
       Date1        Date2       Date3
     13/12/2019   2018/05/21   21/05/2019
     2019/13/12   21/05/21     05/21/2019
```

The date format inside a variable and across variables are different. I want to convert it to as.Date as one common format `"%d/%m%Y"` for all variables at once.
How do I do it?

Kindly help.

Comment: My data has also got other variables like X,Y,Z along with Date1 Date2 and Date3. DF[,c(4,5,6)] should get converted to as.Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be `parse_date_time`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
   mutate_all(parse_date_time, orders = c("mdy", "ymd", "dmy", "ydm"))
#      Date1      Date2      Date3
#1 2019-12-13 2018-05-21 2019-05-21
#2 2019-12-13 2021-05-21 2019-05-21
```

---

or another option is `anydate` from `anytime`.  Check whether all the formats are there in the default format list with `getFormats()` and if some are missing, add those with `addFormats` and then apply on each column

```
library(anytime)
addFormats(c("%d/%m/%Y", "%Y/d/%m", "%d/%m/%y"))
df1 %>% 
   mutate_all(anydate)
```

If there are more columns and want to implement only for 'Date' columns, use `mutate_at`

```
df1 %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Date")), anydate)
```

Or specify the index (in the original dataset)

```
df1 %>%
    mutate_at(4:6, anydate)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date1 = c("13/12/2019", "2019/13/12"), Date2 = c("2018/05/21", 
 "21/05/21"), Date3 = c("21/05/2019", "05/21/2019")),
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -2L))
```

Comment: Okay. My data has also got categorical variables. Can I do this operation selecting only date type variables and apply parse_date_time? Is that possible?

Comment: @JenniferTherese. Then use `mutate_at` with vars specied `mutate_at(vars(matches("Date\\d+")), parse_date_time, ...`